# Rails routing based on GET params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want such a routing table:

```
"/search" => "search#home" # Without GET params, call action "home".
"/search?*" => "search#result" # Call "result" action when search has params.
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an [advanced constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Check for the presence of a query string. I think you'd need to put this ahead of the home route.

(This is all untested/unconfirmed.)